# Is $x^{-0}$ defined?

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, notation

In the form of mathematics that most of humanity is taught, the following operation is undefined:

$\Large{\frac{x}{0}}$

But, how about the following operation?

$\Large{x^{-0}}$

Is the following statement true?

$\Large{x^{-0}=\frac{1}{x^0}=\frac{1}{1}=1}$

Comment: Note that $\,-0 = 0\,$ since $\,0+0= 0\,\ $

Comment: As long as $\;x\neq0\;$ ...

Comment: @BillDubuque - That's awesome! Math is one tight dolphin. :O

Comment: Since $-0=0$, obviously $x^{-0}=x^0$.

Comment: @DonAntonio $0^0=1$. It is just that $x_n\to 0$ and $y_n\to 0$ fails to imply $x_n^{y_n}\to 1$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen From the right. From the left there are big problems with $\;x^x\;$ : it isn't defined in any right neighborhood of zero.

Comment: I usually tend to define $\;0^0:=1\;$, just making sure that *real* exponential functions require a positive base.

Comment: My comment can be read in : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power

Answer (score 7):

Yes. $-0=0$, hence $x^{-0}=x^0=1$.

**Addendum:** see DonAntonio's comment below.

Comment: As long as $\;x\neq0\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: true. Though $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} x^x=1$, so in most contexts the definition $0^0=1$ is harmless.

Comment: Yes, but in fact it must be the right sided limit $\;x\to 0^+\;$ , as the left one doesn't exist as the function $\;x^x\;$ isn't defined in any left neighborhood of zero

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. +1

Answer (score 4):

A bit off discussion, but it may be dangerous to assign a value to $0^0$ as two non-commuting limits are involved. Any positive real number is possible. Given $a>0$ and
'define' (which I wouldn't recommend doing, though):
$$ 0^0 = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} x^{y(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} \exp(\log x \; y(x)),$$
where $y(x)$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to zero.
Choosing $y(x)=\log a/\log x$ (which indeed goes to zero as $x$ goes to zero):
$$ 0^0 = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} x^{y(x)} = \exp\left(\log x \frac{\log a}{ \log x}\right) = a.$$ 
Later edit: This suggests better leave this case undefined when context indicates that powers are in ${\Bbb R}$ or ${\Bbb C}$. There is a broad general concensus (of algebraic and practical nature, binomial formula, Taylor series,...) of defining $x^0 =1$ for any real or complex $x$ whenever the context indicates that powers are in ${\Bbb N}$.

Comment: There need not be any limits at all involved. Indeed, in a lot of contexts, the only exponents that appear are integers.

Comment: True. If we are dealing with integer exponents then $z^0=1$ for $z>0$ admits analytic continuation to the complex plane, so that gives an argument in favor.

Comment: Do you always write $e^x=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ instead of $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$?

Comment: No, I must admit ;-)  But sometimes when dealing with (square) matrices or operators, I write: $\exp(A) = {\bf 1} + \sum_{n\geq 1} A^n/n!$. Anyway I agree that if the context is integer exponents it seems reasonable to say $x^0=1$ for any $x$.

Comment: This "answer" (though it's not answering anything the OP has asked) is simply wrong. The limiting behaviour of $f(x,y) = x^y$ as $x,y \to 0$ is irrelevant (or you can have $y$ be a function of $x$, it doesn't matter). We want the value at the point. That's it. If the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$, so what? $0^0 = 1$, the empty product; this has been the consensus among mathematicians for quite some time.

Comment: Edit to my previous comment: according to the other answers and Wiki, there are some in the mathematical community who say $0^0$ is undefined. So there is no consensus. Nevertheless I find it odd and the reasoning is rather unconvincing.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1223154/34930) for my take on the issue.

Answer (score 3):

$x^0=1$ for all $x$ *except* $x=0$, which some conventions have undefined while others set equal to $1$ (see [Zero to the zero power - is $0^0=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1)). This means that $x^{-0}=1$ for all $x$ *except* $x=0$, for which it is (depending on convention) either undefined or $1$. This has nothing to do with the fact that $x\over 0$ is *always* undefined.

---

I should add that I am strongly in favor of "$0^0=1$" - to my mind there's no question that this is the "right" definition - but there are definitely people out there who disagree, and I have seen some professional mathematicians treat $0^0$ as undefined, so I'm erring on the side of caution above.

Comment: Mathematics shouldn't be about opinion. There is only truth and untruth. If some mathematicians leave $0^0$ as undefined, why are they not refuted? You would think after all these years we'd have a consensus.

Comment: The statement "There is only truth and untruth" is false. There is also undecidability. For example, Gödel's incompleteness theorems. Also, one cannot say $x=y$ is true or not, if $x$ and $y$ are not defined and/or if the context of the equation is not fully known.

Answer (score 1):

$x^y=e^{ylog(x)}$ so $x^0=x^{-0}$ are defined for $x>0$.

Comment: Thanks! What if $x=0$? What if $x < 0$?

Comment: I think bringing logs into this overcomplicates things, since it makes the $x<0$ case seem mysterious.

Comment: The case $x<0$, $y\neq 0$ is quite non-trivial unless $y$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two principles: "anything to the power $0$ is $1$" and "$0$ raised to any positive power is $0$". It makes sense to allow the first principle to define $0^0:=1$, because there is no reason for the second principle to extend to $0^0$, as it clearly does not extend to any negative power, and there are abundant examples, such as $\lim_{x\to0+}x^x=1$, which would violate it. That said, one can easily find examples where such a limit may not be $1$: Consider $\lim_{x\to0+}y^x$, which is $0$ in the case that $y=\exp(-1/x^2)$ although both $x$ and $y$ go to $0$. It is probably because of cases like this that some mathematicians are uncomfortable with the convention that $0^0=1$, and prefer to consider it undefined.